# To find analytic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

An analytic function $f(z)$ is such that $Re(f'(z))=2y$ and $f(1+i)=2$. Then the imaginary part of $f(z)$ is

$A.$ $-2xy$

$B.$ $x^{2}-y^{2}$

$C.$ $2xy$

$D.$ $y^{2}-x^{2}.$

Since $f(1+i)=2$ so $A$ and $C$ is not correct. How to decide from $B$ and $D?$
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $v_{y}=2y$ so $v=y^{2}-x^{2}?$ Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Cauchy-Riemann equations $u_x'=v_y'$ and $u_y'=-v_x'$.

For $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

- $\Re f'=u_x'=2y$ gives $u=2xy+\phi(y)$
- $\Re f'=v_y'=2y$ gives $v=y^2+\psi(x)$
- $u_y'=2x+\phi'(y)=-v_x'=-\psi'(x)$ $\implies$ $\psi(x)=-x^2+C$

It yields $v=y^2-x^2+C$. Furthermore, $C=0$ because $\Im f(1+i)=v(1,1)=0$.